# Jquery: Trigger multiple actions from single events - or -

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to make a single event update two parts of the page.

If you look at http://eddowding.com/clients/stack/OverviewLite.php you can zoom on the top graph by clicking and dragging an area. On release this updates one of the graphs on the page. I'd like it to update all of them.

I think this is a jquery issue, not a flot issue, and suspect that Fling (http://www.command-tab.com/2008/12/04/jquery-fling/) might hold an answer. But I can't quite work out how to apply it. (I'm not a js guy by any means..!)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Graph Hell!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
    <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/flot/excanvas.pack.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.fling.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var d = [
                [1196463600000, 500],
                [1196550000000, 0],
                [1196636400000, 0],
                [1196722800000, 77],
                [1196809200000, 3636],
                [1196895600000, 3575],
                [1196982000000, 2736],
                [1197068400000, 1086],
                [1197154800000, 676],
                [1197241200000, 1205],
                [1197327600000, 906],
                [1197414000000, 710],
                [1197500400000, 639],
                [1197586800000, 540],
                [1197673200000, 435],
                [1197759600000, 301],
                [1197846000000, 575],
                [1197932400000, 481],
                [1198018800000, 591],
                [1198105200000, 608],
                [1198191600000, 459],
                [1198278000000, 234],
                [1198364400000, 1352],
                [1198450800000, 686],
                [1198537200000, 279],
                [1198623600000, 449],
                [1198710000000, 468],
                [1198796400000, 392],
                [1198882800000, 282],
                [1198969200000, 208],
                [1199055600000, 229],
                [1199142000000, 177],
                [1199228400000, 374],
                [1199314800000, 436],
                [1199401200000, 404],
                [1199487600000, 253],
                [1199574000000, 218],
                [1199660400000, 476],
                [1199746800000, 462],
                [1199833200000, 448],
                [1199919600000, 442],
                [1200006000000, 403],
                [1200092400000, 204],
                [1200178800000, 194],
                [1200265200000, 327],
                [1200351600000, 374],
                [1200438000000, 507],
                [1200524400000, 546],
                [1200610800000, 482],
                [1200697200000, 283],
                [1200783600000, 221],
                [1200870000000, 483],
                [1200956400000, 523],
                [1201042800000, 528],
                [1201129200000, 483],
                [1201215600000, 452],
                [1201302000000, 270],
                [1201388400000, 222],
                [1201474800000, 439],
                [1201561200000, 559],
                [1201647600000, 521],
                [1201734000000, 477],
                [1201820400000, 442],
                [1201906800000, 252],
                [1201993200000, 236],
                [1202079600000, 525],
                [1202166000000, 477],
                [1202252400000, 386],
                [1202338800000, 409],
                [1202425200000, 408],
                [1202511600000, 237],
                [1202598000000, 193],
                [1202684400000, 357],
                [1202770800000, 414],
                [1202857200000, 393],
                [1202943600000, 353],
                [1203030000000, 364],
                [1203116400000, 215],
                [1203202800000, 214],
                [1203289200000, 356],
                [1203375600000, 399],
                [1203462000000, 334],
                [1203548400000, 348],
                [1203634800000, 243],
                [1203721200000, 126],
                [1203807600000, 157],
                [1203894000000, 288]
            ];


            var e = [
                [1196463600000, -500],
                [1196550000000, -0],
                [1196636400000, -0],
                [1196722800000, -77],
                [1196809200000, -3636],
                [1196895600000, -3575],
                [1196982000000, -2736],
                [1197068400000, -1086],
                [1197154800000, -676],
                [1197241200000, -1205],
                [1197327600000, -906],
                [1197414000000, -710],
                [1197500400000, -639],
                [1197586800000, -540],
                [1197673200000, -435],
                [1197759600000, -301],
                [1197846000000, -575],
                [1197932400000, -481],
                [1198018800000, -591],
                [1198105200000, -608],
                [1198191600000, -459],
                [1198278000000, -234],
                [1198364400000, -1352],
                [1198450800000, -686],
                [1198537200000, -279],
                [1198623600000, -449],
                [1198710000000, -468],
                [1198796400000, -392],
                [1198882800000, -282],
                [1198969200000, -208],
                [1199055600000, -229],
                [1199142000000, -177],
                [1199228400000, -374],
                [1199314800000, -436],
                [1199401200000, -404],
                [1199487600000, -253],
                [1199574000000, -218],
                [1199660400000, -476],
                [1199746800000, -462],
                [1199833200000, -448],
                [1199919600000, -442],
                [1200006000000, -403],
                [1200092400000, -204],
                [1200178800000, -194],
                [1200265200000, -327],
                [1200351600000, -374],
                [1200438000000, -507],
                [1200524400000, -546],
                [1200610800000, -482],
                [1200697200000, -283],
                [1200783600000, -221],
                [1200870000000, -483],
                [1200956400000, -523],
                [1201042800000, -528],
                [1201129200000, -483],
                [1201215600000, -452],
                [1201302000000, -270],
                [1201388400000, -222],
                [1201474800000, -439],
                [1201561200000, -559],
                [1201647600000, -521],
                [1201734000000, -477],
                [1201820400000, -442],
                [1201906800000, -252],
                [1201993200000, -236],
                [1202079600000, -525],
                [1202166000000, -477],
                [1202252400000, -386],
                [1202338800000, -409],
                [1202425200000, -408],
                [1202511600000, -237],
                [1202598000000, -193],
                [1202684400000, -357],
                [1202770800000, -414],
                [1202857200000, -393],
                [1202943600000, -353],
                [1203030000000, -364],
                [1203116400000, -215],
                [1203202800000, -214],
                [1203289200000, -356],
                [1203375600000, -399],
                [1203462000000, -334],
                [1203548400000, -348],
                [1203634800000, -243],
                [1203721200000, -126],
                [1203807600000, -157],
                [1203894000000, -288]
            ];

            // first correct the timestamps - they are recorded as the daily
            // midnights in UTC+0100, but Flot always displays dates in UTC
            // so we have to add one hour to hit the midnights in the plot
            for (var i = 0; i < d.length; ++i)
                d[i][0] += 60 * 60 * 1000;

            // helper for returning the weekends in a period
            function weekendAreas(axes) {
                var markings = [];
                var d = new Date(axes.xaxis.min);
                // go to the first Saturday
                d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() - ((d.getUTCDay() + 1) % 7))
                d.setUTCSeconds(0);
                d.setUTCMinutes(0);
                d.setUTCHours(0);
                var i = d.getTime();
                do {
                    // when we don't set yaxis the rectangle automatically
                    // extends to infinity upwards and downwards
                    markings.push({
                        xaxis: {
                            from: i,
                            to: i + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                        }
                    });
                    i += 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
                } while (i < axes.xaxis.max);

                return markings;
            }

            var options1 = {
                colors: ["#00ff00", "#ff0000"],
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: []
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: []
                },
                selection: {
                    mode: "x"
                },
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },
                grid: {
                    markings: weekendAreas,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            };

            var options2 = {
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time"
                },
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 5
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: [],
                    min: -4000,
                    max: 5000
                },
                selection: {
                    mode: "x",
                    color: "#45A0DC"
                },
                grid: {
                    markings: weekendAreas,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            };

            var options3 = {
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                shadowSize: 0,
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: [],
                    mode: "time"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: [],
                    min: 0,
                    max: 4000
                },
                grid: {
                    markings: weekendAreas,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            };

            var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d, e], options1);

            var overviewMini = $.plot($("#overviewMini"), [d, e], {
                colors: ["#00ff00", "#ff0000"],
                legend: {
                    show: true,
                    container: $("#overviewLegend")
                },
                lines: {
                    show: true,
                    lineWidth: 2
                },
                shadowSize: 0,
                xaxis: {
                    ticks: [],
                    mode: "time"
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ticks: [],
                    min: -4000,
                    max: 4000
                },
                selection: {
                    mode: "x",
                    color: "#45A0DC"
                },
                grid: {
                    markings: weekendAreas,
                    borderWidth: 0
                }
            });

            var datesOnly = $.plot($("#datesOnly"), [d, e], options2);


            var salary = $.plot($("#salary"), [d], options3);

            var plotType = 0;


            // now for the binding between the graphs


            $("#placeholder").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
                // do the zooming
                // don't fire event on the incomeMini to prevent eternal loop
                overviewMini.setSelection(ranges, true);
                zoomGraphs(ranges);
            });

            $("#datesOnly").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
                // do the zooming

                // don't fire event on the incomeMini to prevent eternal loop
                overviewMini.setSelection(ranges, true);
                zoomGraphs(ranges);
            });

            $("#salary").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
                // do the zooming
                // don't fire event on the incomeMini to prevent eternal loop
                overviewMini.setSelection(ranges, true);
                zoomGraphs(ranges);
            });

            $("#overviewMini").bind("plotselected", function (event, ranges) {
                zoomGraphs(ranges);
            });

            function zoomGraphs(ranges) {
                $.plot($("#datesOnly"), [d, e],
                    $.extend(true, {}, options2, {
                        xaxis: {
                            min: ranges.xaxis.from,
                            max: ranges.xaxis.to
                        }
                    }));

                $.plot($("#placeholder"), [d, e],
                    $.extend(true, {}, options1, {
                        xaxis: {
                            min: ranges.xaxis.from,
                            max: ranges.xaxis.to
                        }
                    }));

                $.plot($("#salary"), [d, e],
                    $.extend(true, {}, options3, {
                        xaxis: {
                            min: ranges.xaxis.from,
                            max: ranges.xaxis.to
                        }
                    }));
            }
        });
    </script>
    <div id="overviewMini" style="width:400px;height:50px"></div>
    <div id="datesOnly" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="placeholder" style="width:400px;height:100px;"></div>
    <div id="salary" style="width:400px;height:50px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks to Sean at YellowLabs.nl and #jquery IRC!!!

Comment: Nice thing to answer yourself! Thats the spirit.